# Cannot get data from Google analytics downloader in CloudConnect

Tags: google-analytics-api, data-integration, gooddata

I create new GA connection for Google Analytics Reader component in GoodData Cloudconnect. Validation of connection is ok. I set up GA reader. I choose profile id from list. Everything seems fine. I run graph localy and then I get error:

```
Poll returned status 410: Gone "Worker task failed: Google Analytics username and password combination is invalid. Please verify and try again."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honza,

We have a Zendesk Reader for Zendesk data and a Google Analytics Connector/Reader combination for Google Analytics data that are different. I will assume from the error that the issue is with the Google Analytics Connector and Reader combination.

I would start by re-verifying all the credential settings of course. There is an article for [loading data from GA](http://developer.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/ch15.html). Make sure at the connection component level that the "test connection" functionality is saying everything is OK. Then I would open the Google Analytics Reader component and verify the Profile ID drop down is populated properly and you can see the active lists of GA profiles for the credentials. If the credentials are wrong you will not be able to select an active Profile ID. Also verify that the all the other necessary reader components are set related to the connection. "Dimensions and Metrics" as well as the Start and End Dates.

If this is all OK you might want to explore the idea that Google Analytics is blocking the requests when running locally in GoodData. There is an article on updating your Google Account  here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en

I would also validate you are using the latest version of CloudConnect by using the Check for Updates... option in the CloudConnect help menu.

If you still cannot get the connection setup or the graph to run I would suggest contacting support. You can contact our Global Support Team by emailing support@gooddata.com. We would need your ETL project for deep investigation. So I would suggest you should export and attach the ETL project to the ticket. (right click on the ETL project => Export => "Archive File" then Next => check ETL project, select what you want to export (default is all ETL project), choose place for export, choose zip and Finish).

Please follow up in this forum so we can see the final resolution (even if it goes to support) and good luck.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Thanks Jason, the problem was really in Google blocking request when running graph locally.

Comment: Glad to hear the final resolution and I am happy that it was one of the suggested solutions in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. This problem is related to the Google’s Account Protection feature. Check https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en for more information about your situation.

Even when running a graph locally some parts might be running on server. In this case the functionality that reads the data runs on the server and you will be seeing accesses from one of our servers.

### Solution

Acknowledge the login attempt as legitimate as it is coming from GoodData platform. Once Google stops blocking the login attempts from GoodData platform the reader will be able to pull the data.

After the accesses are confirmed as legitimate run the graph again.